# How to change SSMS warning settings on SQL without any queries?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, options-menu, ssms-2012

I believe there is a SSMS setting somewhere in the options menu to allow changes to tables that require dropping and recreating. How do i do it? I hope I'm being clear with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the 2008 R2 tools but I believe it's in the same place.

Tools - Options - Designers - Table and Database Designers - Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation.

[image]

Comment: I'm released! Thanks a lot, this is what I need. Yes, it's the same way for SQL Server 2012